# How can I ensure my filter function finishes before my Axios call to prevent undefined variable error in Vue.js 2 with Axios?

Tags: json, vuejs2, axios

I am getting an undefined variable when stringifying my filtered array and parsing it in my backend (Via axios).

My problem is that the error is thrown on my live server (not everytime, maybe 1 of 1000 calls) and the only way i can reproduce it is by setting a timeout function to my filter function, thus having an undefined variable when calling my axios function.

So my code does the following:
(Please keep in mind that the setTimeout is there to simulate my filtering function taking too long)

```js
let mainArray = []

let filterArray

setTimeout(() => {
  filterArray = mainArray.filter((obj) => {
      return obj.id === 1;
  })
}, 1000)

// call of axios function with parameters:
let frontendArray = JSON.stringify(filterArray);

// backend function that throws the error because by array is undefined
let backendArray = JSON.parse(frontendArray);

console.log(backendArray)
```

My guess is that my filter function takes too long so my axios call fires before my fitlerArray is filled.

I could go around my error by predefining my filterArray as an empty array, but that way there is a chance that i am not getting my data to my backend.

What would be the best way to solve this? Should i simply wait for my filter function or is there a better way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think javascript [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) is the solution for you, here is what you could do :

```
<script>
  const mainArray = [];

  let filterArray;

  // Promise to launch initialisation of frontendArray stringify when filterArray is filled
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    filterArray = mainArray.filter((obj) => {
      return obj.id === 1;
    });
    resolve(filterArray);
  });

  promise.then((result) => {
    // call of axios function with parameters:
    const frontendArray = JSON.stringify(filterArray);

    // backend function that throws the error because by array is undefined
    const backendArray = JSON.parse(frontendArray);

    console.log(backendArray);
  });
</script>
```

You could also use [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) from Vue2,
Hope it works for you !